# How to send JavaScript variables to Java applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have a JavaScript function which is:

```
function printreceipt(tax,subtotal,total)
{
subtotalElem=document.getElementById("total");
var taxElem=document.getElementById("tax");
productElem=document.getElementById("product-name");
alert("here are my products" + taxElem.innerHTML + subtotalElem.innerHTML);
}
```

How to send JavaScript variables to Java applet?

Answer (score 5):

Your applet should have a public method , for example receiveData() :

```
public void receiveData(String dataFromJS)
{
   //Do what you need with your data
}
```

Let's say you have something like that in your web page :

```
<applet id ="appletID" name="myApplet" ... ></applet>
```

In your javascript you just have to call the applet public method like this :

```
var myApp = document.applets['myApplet'];
myApp.receiveData(taxElem.innerHTML + subtotalElem.innerHTML);
```

The previous example will send the taxElem and subtotalElem content to the applet.

To send data from Applet to JS you sould use [JSObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html)  in your applet

Comment: the content is not shown as string.how can the content be shown as string in the above case.

Comment: how should i pass the data like the tax to the parameter passed datafromJS

Comment: Simply call the method. If you do myApp.receiveData('this my data'); The parameter dataFromJs in your applet will contain the string used in JS. String is not mandatory , you can use int or whatever you need

Comment: means the parameter dataFromJS will contain string which is in the "eg " taxElem.innerHTML.

Comment: will i add more parameters or the 1 above will display the whole string

Comment: You can add parameter if you need. Sending data to your applet is exactly the same thing as sending data to an other javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use netscape.javascript.**JSObject** for Java-to-JS direction or **reference the applet by its id** for JS-to-Java.

See here for detailed example : http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/10/java-applets-building-with-maven.html

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to do this is to open a new page with the parameters encoded in the URL, then write those parameters as into an applet element as `param` elements.  (Though +1 to each of the other answers.)

Comment: the applet is not receiving the informatio as a string.how can i do that.