# JavaScript Communicating With Applet

Tags: java, javascript, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing data between javascript and a java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124758/passing-data-between-javascript-and-a-java-applet)

I have this function in java applet

```
public void receiveData(String DatafromJS){}
```

and this function in JavaScript

```
function printreceipt(tax,subtotal,total)
{
 subtotalElem=document.getElementById("total");
 taxElem=document.getElementById("tax");

 var myApp = document.applets['myApplet'];
 myApp.receiveData(taxElem.innerHTML + subtotalElem.innerHTML);
}
```

I want to pass JavaScript variables, like tax inform of a string.  I wish to see the values of those variables in the applet.  Could someone help me with how to pass the data.  I want the applet to send that data to another class which is a `jni`, since I want to be printing this information using a fiscal printer.

Comment: Are you trying to use JNI to interface between Java and JavaScript?  JNI is designed to allow Java to interoperate with C, C++, etc, not JavaScript.

Comment: no i will add jni to interface with a certain file FiscPrintDLL.dll which will communicate with serial port like com1.i will add another class of jni which will call methods of the java applet and its parameters.please help

Comment: How is the user going to get FiscPrintDLL.dll in the first place?  It seems like your problem would be best solved by developing a desktop application, not an applet.

Comment: i have another application which is point of sale in which i have added the javascript function.the FiscPrintDLL.dll is used to interface with a fiscal printer.

Comment: *"I have this function in java applet"*  Didn't occur to you to add the ***applet*** tag?  How exactly does this differ to [your 2 earlier questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1328953/rose-wangui?tab=questions) on the matter?  Do you intend to keep asking the question until someone 'gives you teh codez'?  -1 & voting to close.

Comment: Also voting to close.  Please don't duplicate your own question.

Answer (score 2):

I was pretty sure this was impossible but apparently not!

[Here are the official Java docs on doing this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html)